# How to make bot move all members to another voice channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I've been having troubles with this command event. I wanted to play a sound that's called `options.ogg`, The bot can join the voice channel and play the audio just fine, but afterwards it produces an error `InvalidArgument: The channel provided must be a voice channel`. I tried reading it, but I've had trouble understanding how it works exactly. So basically I want the bot to play that sound, then move all members from the voice chat it joined to another voice chat.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
   async def selfdestruct(ctx):
   author = ctx.message.author
   voice_chat = author.voice_channel
   vc = await client.join_voice_channel(voice_chat)
   channel = '282328034474983425'
  player = vc.create_ffmpeg_player('C:\sound\options.ogg', after=lambda: 
 print('done'))
player.start()
while not player.is_done():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
# disconnect after the player has finished
player.stop()

await vc.disconnect()
await client.move_member(author, channel)
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a `move_member()` method for the client in the current API documentation for 1.3.0a. That being said the current documentation shows it should be `member.move_to()`. The channel should also be converted to an integer. You may also want to try something like `channel = client.get_channel(channel_id_goes_here)` - take a look at https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member. I can provide a further code update when I am able to do so if this doesn't fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer was in the comment, I figured I would make an official one after the fact for anyone else.

Basically, in this particular question, the individual was trying to use a method `move_member()` which does not exist in the current documentation.

It was suggested to use `member.move_to()` and that they needed to convert the channel from a string id to an integer id.

The following line should be changed from:

`channel = '282328034474983425'`

to

`channel = client.get_channel(282328034474983425)`